# freeipa server home directory automount

Tags: authentication, freeipa, home-directory, autofs, automount

I have installed freeipa-server on centos and enrolled an ubuntu server to it, I have a freebsd server which is our storage server(I am going to enrolled the freebsd (storage server) to this freeipa-server), I want to host the home-directory of the users on it and want to know if the home-directory can be auto-mounted when the user logs in to any machine which is enrolled to this freeipa-server. I am also wondering if the home-directories can be created automatically when the users get created on the freeipa-server.
Does any one know if its possible ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn't your own screenshot already answer the "Is it possible"?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean, can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

'Home directory' field is used for specifying the local home directory on the host, e.g. `/home/username`, the location where a shell would default to after login.

Auto-mounting a network-provided share to that directory is possible, same as without FreeIPA. Auto-creation of new network mount on a first login is not possible without compromising security of your networking storage. A system you are logging into has no permissions to create a new network volume at your remote server. You need to consider that.